# WinApi при попытке записать в mailslot получаю отказано в доступе

Tags: c++, winapi

Имею 2 процесса, один считывает данные пользователя другой считывает их. Первый процесс должен записать в mailslot данные, другой считать. При попытке записать получаю ошибку 5 отказано в доступе, а при чтении 87 параметр задан неверно. С плюсами знаком плохо, сам пишу на другом языке. Это нужно чисто для универа.
Как это исправить?

Первый процесс

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE m = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, L"MyMutex");
    if (m == 0)
        return -1;

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (CreateProcess(L"c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Lab3\\Procces1\\Debug\\Procces1.exe", NULL,
        NULL, NULL, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) == TRUE) {

        bool flagEnd = true;
        double a,b,c;

        HANDLE mail = CreateMailslot(L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Lab3\\mail", 0, MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER, NULL);
        if (mail == 0)
            return -1;

        while (true) {
            WaitForSingleObject(m, INFINITE);
            cout << "Please enter A and B values\n";
            cout << "A = ";
            cin >> a;
            cout << "B = ";
            cin >> b;

            WriteFile(mail, &a, sizeof(double), NULL, NULL);
            WriteFile(mail, &b, sizeof(double), NULL, NULL);
            cout << GetLastError();


            ReleaseMutex(m);
        }


        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(m);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Process has not been created\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Второй процесс

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE mut = OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, L"MyMutex");
    if (mut == 0)
        return -1;

    HANDLE mail = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Lab3\\mail", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (mail == 0)
        return -1;


    double a, b, c;
    DWORD byte;
    while (true) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mut, INFINITE);
        cout << "Reading\n";

        ReadFile(mail, &a, sizeof(double), NULL, NULL);


        ReadFile(mail, &b, sizeof(double), NULL, NULL);
        cout << GetLastError();
        cout << "I have read " << a << " " << b << endl;
        ReleaseMutex(mut);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

могу ошибаться, но после CreteFile/CreateMailslot в проверке хэндла надо ставить не 0, а INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (а он не ноль. #define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR)-1)). Есть и другие ошибки.
Накидал Рабочий пример чтение/запись. Надеюсь поможет

```
HANDLE mail = CreateMailslot(L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\mylab", 0, MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER, NULL);
if(mail==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return 0;
HANDLE wh =  CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\mailslot\\mylab", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if(wh==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return 0;

static LPTSTR MyMessage = L"1234567890";
BOOL     err;
DWORD    numWritten;

err = WriteFile(wh, MyMessage, 10, &numWritten, 0);
DWORD  cbMessages;
DWORD  cbMsgNumber;
err = GetMailslotInfo(mail, NULL, &cbMessages,&cbMsgNumber, NULL);
if(!err){
      fprintf(stdout,"GetMailslotInfo: Error %ld\n",
        GetLastError());
    }
char* buf = (char*)LocalAlloc(LPTR,cbMessages*cbMsgNumber+1);
ReadFile(mail,(LPVOID)buf,cbMessages*cbMsgNumber,&numWritten, 0);

LocalFree((LPVOID)buf);
```

Comment: Так он нормально создает, а вот записать не пишет

Comment: добавил пример. разбирайтесь. удачи в учебе